# How to change the label format on x-axis of Tikz pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, labels

I am trying to make a nice looking histogram of my data, and have managed to produce the following so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=8000,
    minor y tick num = 2,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
    area style,
    ]
\addplot+ [ybar interval,mark=no, fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135},draw=gray!5] plot coordinates { (0, 32) (5, 1228) (10, 6658) (15, 5060) (20, 1786) (25, 684) (30, 404) (35, 228) (40, 165) (45, 119) (50, 72)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I would like is to make the x-labels read: 0.0x, 5.0x, 10.0x etc. How would I go about this?

Comment: why don't you use TikZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this or do you want to divide the number by 2?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=8000,
    minor y tick num = 2,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
    area style,
    xticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=1,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}x,
    ]
\addplot+ [ybar interval,mark=no, fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135},draw=gray!5] plot coordinates { (0, 32) (5, 1228) (10, 6658) (15, 5060) (20, 1786) (25, 684) (30, 404) (35, 228) (40, 165) (45, 119) (50, 72)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This completely solved my issue, thank you very much!